# Issue with UWP getHtmlPrintDocumentSourceAsync( when used along with x-ms-webview)

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, webview, uwp

My app uses x-ms-webview for other requirements. We create the HTML element x-ms-webview and add it to DOM. After its functionality is done, we remove it from DOM.

My app also uses Windows document Printing. It uses Windows.Graphics.Printing(PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync). The data to printed is converted to HTMLDocumnentSource using the API MSApp.getHtmlPrintDocumentSourceAsync(page)

I notice this error, that whenever the x-ms-webview is removed from DOM, the MSApp.getHtmlPrintDocumentSourceAsync(page) throws the below error
Unhandled exception at line 357, column 1 in res://edgehtml.dll/preview.js​
​0x8000ffff - JavaScript runtime error: Unexpected call to method or property access

This is sample code

```
1. Create a sample Cordova UWP app.
2. Add the x-ms-webview for example on button click as shown below


     var wv =  document.createElement('x-ms-webview'); // Use CSS to  set width, height and other styles
        wv.navigate("https://www.example.com");
         wv.id = "test145";
3. Now remove the web view on another action as shown below:
    var obj1=  document.getElementById(“test145”)
    obj1.parentNode.removeChild(obj1)
4. Try to perform printing, invoke as shown below:
    Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.showPrintUIAsync()
```

The removal of x-ms-webview from the DOM causes this issue. If I hide the webview, the issue is not seen. Does anybody know what the dependency of the webview with these Printer API. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for more diagnosis.

Comment: I have added the sample code for this issue

Comment: If you have problems calling **PrintManager**, you can try using `window.print()`. It is a native JS printing method that can call Windows printer programs to achieve your purpose.

Comment: Thanks Richasy. This helps me for until I get a solution for PrintManager error.